# What's the new lambda syntax?

Tags: lambda, d

I've heard there is going to be a new syntax in DMD 2.058 for anonymous functions, but I can't find any information on it. What is the new syntax, and is the old syntax going to be deprecated?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe it's like [C#'s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

The following are equivalent:

```
delegate(i, j) { return i + j; }
(i, j) => i + j
```

as are:

```
delegate(i) { return i; }
(i) => i
i => i   // Can leave off parentheses
```

as are:

```
delegate(int i) { return i; }
(int i) => i
```

though I'm not sure whether explicit return types are also supported in the new syntax.

Comment: Seems a bit silly to ask, but I assume `(x) => {return x;}` form is also supported?  That is, using the operator with a statement block delimited by curly braces is valid?

Answer (score 8):

No current lambda functionality is being removed. It's just that a new, terser syntax is being introduced for those who want it. As [Merhdad says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8857984/160887), it's essentially C#'s syntax, though I don't know if it's 100% identical.

So instead of doing something like

```
auto found = find!((a){return func(a) == value;})(range);
```

you do something like

```
auto found = find!(a => func(a) == value)(range);
```